# Finding Tella in Ethiopia (on fasting days)

Tags: alcohol, ethiopia, addis-ababa

I will have a stopover Addis Ababa, and am interested in trying [*tella*, an Ethiopian beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tella). I have heard that Ethiopians typically "fast" on Fridays. Does the fast include abstention from alcohol? Is tella something I'll find in easily, or do I need to know where to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, but read on !

Ethiopians are predominantly Orthodox Christians or Muslims. It goes without saying you probably won't be served alcohol in a Muslim household. For those of Christian faith, they do in fact [fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Orthodox_Tewahedo_Church#Practices_and_beliefs) on [Fridays](http://www.goorsha.net/fasting-in-ethiopia/) but the abstention is from animal products and sex, no mention of alcohol.

That said, *tella* is not something you'd typically find sold commercially, it's a [homemade](http://www.journalofethnicfoods.net/article/S2352-6181(15)00042-6/fulltext#sec4) beverage Ethiopians brew at home to serve guests. You can find those in homes, or *tella bet*, a sort of informal bar. [This](http://www.pitt.edu/~kloman/tejbetmaps.html) is a list of *tej bet* where you're likely to find *tella* as well, and if [this](http://cooksipgo.com/tella-ethiopian-home-brew/) article is to be believed, *tella bet* are usually indicated by placing a coloured rag or can on a pole in front of the house